# Calculate Likelihood Function for Gamma/Weibull Distribution

Tags: statistics, bayesian, products

I'm trying to calculate the likelihood function (not log-likelihood) for a random sample of n observations from a Gamma Distribution and a Weibull Distribution and I'm struggling to work with the pi notation as it's not something I've done much before.

So for the Gamma distribution this is what I have:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{x_{i}^{a-1}e^{-bx_{i}}b^a}{\Gamma(a)} 
=\Gamma(a)^{-n}b^{an}e^{-b\sum x_i}\prod_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{a-1} \\
= \Gamma(a)^{-n}b^{an}e^{-bn \bar{x}}\prod_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{a-1}
$$

Is this valid? I just feel uncomfortable with this and feel unsure, also is there a way for me to simplify the remaining product term at all?

For the Weibull, I'm struggling a bit more, this is all I have:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \gamma \lambda x_{i}^{\gamma -1}e^{-\lambda x_{i}^{\gamma}}
= \gamma^{n} \lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda \sum x_{i}^{\gamma}}\prod_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{\gamma -1}
$$

I can't seem to figure out a way to simplify the remaining product and sum of powers of $x_i$

Any help would be appreciated, even some signposting to a resource that explains how to work with products like this as I'm really struggling to find anything.

Comment: Does this help ? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1064212/728796

Comment: @Hamdiken Not particularly no, as they've skipped steps and not written out the full answer. I'd like to understand the process of manipulating these products and what is considered "full simplification". Currently I'm not trying to apply this to MLE, I'm just trying to get the process of finding a likelihood function down.

Comment: The way you manipulate the product is okay. You cannot essentially simplify the remaining product of powers of $x_i$. At most you can write $\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{\gamma-1}$ instead of $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\gamma-1}$.